# Traceback for Phantom KeyError

Tags: python

I have never seen a KeyError traceback that doesn't make immediate sense: it is always pointing at some get item, typically on a dictionary, for a key that does not exist. My mistake.

Here, however, I am getting a KeyError even though (a) every attempted get of a dictionary value is guarded with `.get()` and (b) the KeyError is being thrown for a key whose literal value is not present in my code as a string/key but only as a variable name:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 resp = openai.upload_file(request_body, files=file_handle)

File ~/dev/project/python_modules/libraries/http_client/http_client/resource.py:67, in Resource.__call__(self, request_body, headers, files)
     63 request = self.prepare_request(request_body, headers, files)
     65 request = self.validate_request(request)
---> 67 request = self.before_dispatch_hook(request)
     69 response_future = self.client.dispatch_request(request)
     71 if self.client._within_context:  # noqa: SLF001

File ~/dev/project/python_modules/libraries/openai_client/openai_client/resources/files.py:34, in before_dispatch_hook(self, request)
     32 def before_dispatch_hook(self, request):
     33     file_handle = request.files
---> 34     request.files = [
     35         ("purpose", (None, request.request_body.get('purpose'))),
     36         ("file", (request.request_body.get('file'), file_handle, "application/octet-stream"))
     37     ]
     38     return request

KeyError: 'file_handle'
```

Has anyone ever seen anything like this? I am mystified.

Comment: Have you tried to rename variable `file_handle` to something else to see what happens?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I just did, and changing the variable name to something else (`ghost` in my case) resolves the error. Which is great! But no less mystifying.

Comment: My only idea currently is that you may have used `file_handle` as key in an earlier version and there was some old cached byte code lying around which was out of sync with the source.